# How do I obtain the id of a sibling view in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout

When I click on a view, my click handler is invoked and I have access to the view that was clicked.  Is there a way for me to obtain the id of the right sibling view?  The clicked view is actually one of several child views that are dynamically added to a linearlayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/profile"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    //Dynamically filled
 /LinearLayout
```

So at runtime LinearLayouts will nest inside "profile".  One of these LinearLayouts will be clicked, and I have access to that View.  I want the view directly beneath it, like so:

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/profile"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView></TextView>
        <EditText></EditText>
   /LinearLayout>
```

I want to obtain the id of said EditText, when I have access to the TextView that was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least a couple ways to do this.

1. The simplest is to obtain the parent view of the TextView and find the EditText child this way (substitute your desired  view id):

`EditText e = (EditText) ((LinearLayout) getParent()).findViewById(R.id.edittextid);`

2. A more complex way would be to create custom view for the parent LinearLayout which locates its child views by id and then delivers those ids to child who ask for it by an interface that it implements. The parent should call the child to let it know about itself to call.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the id of edittext in code code at the time when you create it by using setId() method and after that find edittext from that id at clicklistner so your edittext click will work